# SMTP Action Mailer Failover in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, smtp, actionmailer

Sending emails is extremely crucial to our business.  We currently plan on using Mandrill as our primary email provider, but if their service goes down, it is extremely important that we have a backup service (SendGrid) kick in on any failures.

Since the SMTP configuration is loaded in Application.rb (which I believe is only once at application load), how can I intelligently fall back to another SMTP service if sending an email fails?

Comment: Hi, were you able to configure a backup SMTP server? If yes, can you update the question with how you solved this use-case please?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than doing the switching/fallback in Rails, the recommendation [SendGrid gives customers to whom email sending is crucial](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/index.html#--Power-Users-and-High-Volume-Senders) is to setup a local mail server (e.g. using [Postfix](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Mail_Servers/postfix.html)) and setup the mail server to use SendGrid as a smart host.

**In your case**, you would setup Mandrill as the relay server and SendGrid as a backup relay server. Your local server would then take care of sending through Mandrill and SendGrid if Mandrill goes down.

Answer (score -2):

Here is my solution:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def welcome_message(user, custom_email=nil, settings)
    ActionMailer::Base.username = settings["username"]
    ActionMailer::Base.password = settings["password"]
    ActionMailer::Base.server = settings["server"]
    ActionMailer::Base.port = settings["port"]

    target_email = custom_email || user.email
    mail(to: target_email, subject: 'Welcome')
  end
end
```